# Are the eigenvectors in this symmetric matrix orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have matrix A:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -2 \\ -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

First lets solve for the $\lambda$ in:

$| \lambda * I - A | = \begin{vmatrix} \lambda + 1 & 2 \\ 2 & \lambda - 2 \end{vmatrix} = \lambda^2 - \lambda - 2 - 4 = (\lambda - 3)*(\lambda + 2)$

$$ \lambda = {3 , -2 }$$

solve x in the equation $(\lambda * I - A)x = 0$ for each lambda:

For the eigenvector 3:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -2 \\ -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & -2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} -> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

So $$\begin{bmatrix} t_1 \\ t_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -t \\ 2t \end{bmatrix} = t * \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

For eigenvector -2:

$$\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -2 \\ -2 & 2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 2 & -4 \end{bmatrix} -> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

So $$\begin{bmatrix} t_1 \\ t_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2t \\ t \end{bmatrix} = t * \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$(-1,2) \cdot (2,1) = 0$ so orthogonal.

Is this right?

Last related question. Why is this statement true:

[image]

I think I get most of it... but why does an nxn must have n eigenvectors? Is this true that the number of eigenvectors is = number of rows/columns in a square matrix? Why? I think I get why it has n linearly independent eigenvectors

Similarly...does an nxn matrix always have n eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix doesn't always have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors; but when it does, it's diagonalizable.  (Symmetric matrices have this property.)

Your work above looks correct.

Comment: Similarly...does an nxn matrix always have n eigenvalues?

Comment: Over $\mathbb C$ yes, since the characteristic polynomial is degree $n$.

Comment: What is C? What does that latter mean? If a characteristic polynomial is degree 3... does that mean there are 3 eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes (counting multiplicity).  $\mathbb C$ is the field of complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true that the eigenvectors associated to distinct eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are orthogonal.
It is a well known theorem which is proved in linear algebra text books.

Comment: Similarly...does an nxn matrix always have n eigenvalues?